# How to learn the current network scheduler used in my linux machine?

Tags: linux, networking, scheduling, packet

How can I learn what network scheduler for packet selection is used in my linux system?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `tc qdisc show` command. The second field is the network scheduler. The default, [pfifo_fast](http://linux.die.net/man/8/tc-pfifo_fast) is basically first in, first out within a priority with higher priorities always going before lower priorities.